# Trouble launching Andengine Activity from OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent, andengine

I have an Activity which is just for displaying the main menu, and then I want to start an Andengine Activity after a Button click.

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);

        TextView nadpis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nadpis);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/DiamondsPearls.ttf");
        nadpis.setTypeface(tf);

        Button playGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playgame);
        playGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonsterTap.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I see an error referring to the line `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonsterTap.class);` that reads

> cannot resolve constructor intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.class)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonsterTap.class);` with `Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, MonsterTap.class);` to properly pass the intent a `Context`.

As you have written it, the `this` keyword is referring to the anonymous inner class representing your `OnClickListener`.